# Easy_install virtualenv/Pip install virtualenv - not working

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv, easy-install

I am working on the company's server and ***pip install*** or ***easy_install*** is not working. I am not able to install ***virtualenv***. This is the result for ***easy_install***:

```
PS C:\> easy_install virtualenv
Searching for virtualenv
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed -- Some packages may not
be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'virtualenv' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or working download links found for virtualenv
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('virtualenv')
PS C:\>
```

This is what I get when I run the pip install command:

```
PS C:\> pip install virtualenv
Collecting virtualenv
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pi
._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03600ED0>: Failed to establish a new
onnection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/virtualenv/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pi
._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03600E10>: Failed to establish a new
onnection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/virtualenv/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pi
._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03600FF0>: Failed to establish a new
onnection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/virtualenv/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pi
._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03600F70>: Failed to establish a new
onnection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/virtualenv/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pi
._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03600EB0>: Failed to establish a new
onnection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/virtualenv/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement virtualenv (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for virtualenv
```

I am new to django and I am not able to figure out the issue. So, please help me with this issue.

Comment: Read the error message, and note that you should check from that same command prompt that `pypi.python.org` is reachable (try `ping pypi.python.org`).

Comment: allow pip in your antiviruses firewall or windows firewall then try again

Comment: @Exprator How do I allow pip through firewall? I tried disabling the firewall. But, I received the same result.

Comment: Try to install this way `pip install virtualenvwrapper-powershell`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

go to this link and search for `virtualenv` and download the proper wheel file and the from the downloads folder

use `pip install the_wheel_name`